# Override the IsAuthenticated permission class with one that checks firebase

Tags: python, django, firebase, pyrebase

I am using firebase(pyrebase library) for my authentication with a django backend and a react frontend.For this to work I had to override the DRF auth class TokenAuthentication with my FirebaseAuthentication. But I still get **401 unauthorised** when I try to access a view since I also need to override the drf permission class i**sAuthenticated**.But I have been searching for a way to do this with python without success.Any help would be appreciated. Below is a snippet of the permission class and where its applied on my views

DRF permissions.py

```
class IsAuthenticated(BasePermission):
    """
    Allows access only to authenticated users.
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_authenticated)
```

views.py

```
class FinanceTransactionList(GenericAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [FirebaseAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @classmethod
    @encryption_check
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement custom permission, override `BasePermission` and implement either, or both, of the following methods:

> .has_permission(self, request, view)
>
> .has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj)

The methods should return `True` if the request should be granted access, and `False` otherwise.

If you need to test if a request is a read operation or a write operation, you should check the request method against the constant `SAFE_METHODS`, which is a tuple containing `'GET'`, `'OPTIONS'`, and `'HEAD'`. For example:

```
if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
    # Check permissions for the read-only request
else:
    # Check permissions for writing request
```

Custom permissions will raise a `PermissionDenied` exception if the test fails. To change the error message associated with the exception, implement a `message` attribute directly on your custom permission. Otherwise, the `default_detail` attribute from `PermissionDenied` will be used. Similarly, to change the code identifier associated with the exception, implement a `code` attribute directly on your custom permission - otherwise, the `default_code` attribute from `PermissionDenied` will be used.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class CustomerAccessPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    message = 'Firebase Auth Required.'

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        ...
```